# MongoDb shows different results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to add a comment object to an array in camps collection.
When i console.log the array i find my added data.
But then i check my data base, i find that the comments array is empty.

```
app.post('/campgrounds/:id/comments', function(req, res){
  Camp.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campComm){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/campgrounds');
    }else{
      Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comm){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          campComm.comments.push(comm);
          console.log(campComm.comments);
          console.log(comm);
          campComm.save();
          console.log(campComm.comments);
          res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campComm._id);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is the Camp Schema

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  img: String,
  description: String,
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Comment"
    }
  ]
});
```

This is the Comment Schema

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  author: String
});
```

Comment: Add a function as the first argument of .save() that receives an error as the first parameter (a callback) and check if you get an error.

Comment: @itsundefined no error !

Comment: Do you get the empty array in `console.log(campComm.comments)` ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi nope, i got all the comments in it, this is really weird

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose` can't track changing in objects or array so you should manually mark that field modified ([see documentation for more details](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified)):

```
campComm.markModified('comments');
campComm.save();
```

Also worth noting that `save` is async so you have to pass callback and perform next steps there (if you want to ensure that your changes have been saved successfukky)

Comment: I think that this's not the problem, because the change had been made in the db, but somehow get's empty again.

Comment: although i added `campComm.markModified('comments');` but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

It was just a typing mistake in populate argument i missed 's'.